# Подсветка ячеек календаря ui datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Есть такой классный календарь, jquery ui datepicker все круто, но тут появились задачи и возникли трудности... а именно:

как можно задать ячейкам календаря, событие онховер hover наведение мыши, пробовал в событии onSelect, когда выбирал дату, ставил это событие $('td a').hover()
но потом выяснил что после этого происходит перерисовка календаря почему то... тоесть вся сетка рисуется заново что делать?

====== добавил

Нет мне нужно чтобы при наведении на дату все даты в диапазоне от текущей до той, на которую навели - подсветились это я так понимаю одним CSS не сделать хотя в CSS3 может и есть что

Вобщем решение не найдено
Жду ваших советов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понял Вам нужно просто применить какой-то стиль при наведении мыши. Значит вам просто надо посмотреть какой класс навешивается на ячейку при наведении и переопределить его в CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Пост древний, но вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится решение -

```
$('td').on('mouseenter', function(){
    var todayIndex = $(this).siblings('.today').index(),
        index      = $(this).index(),
        fromTo     = index < todayIndex ? [index, todayIndex + 1] : [todayIndex, index + 1];

    $("td")
        .removeClass("selected")
        .slice.apply($("td"), fromTo)
        .addClass('selected');
});
```

Результат на http://jsfiddle.net/kkLgs1yv/2/